# Drawing outside edges of a Mesh created from CSG in babylon.js

Tags: babylonjs, csg

I have following scene with csg:
https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#KUM5WC#14
I want to draw only the outside edges of the final plate and the ones of the holes (In playground it needs very long to load and after a rerun one plate is disappearing, you have to reload the page to work again - outside of playground there is no need to refresh the page).

Changing newMeshHolePlate.enableEdgesRendering(0.001); has no effect

My goal is following look:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

do newMeshHolePlate.enableEdgesRendering(0.999) instead of 0.001